# ASP.NET Programmatically enabling Output Caching does not work -> Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0, output-caching

why, in the below aspx and code behind, when Output Caching is enabled programmatically (enabled in code behind), it does not work and has a problem?

**aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="ProgrammaticOutputCaching"
    CodeBehind="ProgrammaticOutputCaching.aspx.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Refresh" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**code behind:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);

        // Use the cached copy of this page for the next 60 seconds.
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
        //Response.Cache.VaryByParams.IgnoreParams = true;

        // This additional line ensures that the browser can't
        // invalidate the page when the user clicks the Refresh button
        // (which some rogue browsers attempt to do).
        Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);

        lblDate.Text = "The time is now:<br>" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

with page directive for output caching there is no problem:
mean
**aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="OutputCaching" CodeBehind="OutputCaching.aspx.cs" %>

<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="Name;Age" Location="Server" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Verdana"
            Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Refresh" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and
**code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        lblDate.Text = "The time is now:<br>";
        lblDate.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

so what is the problem about programmatically?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", do you mean the date is always updated on the page (i.e. it isn't cached), or is there another problem (an exception?)

Comment: @Graham Clark  hi : mean the date is always updated on the page (i.e. it isn't cached),

Comment: also i have no problem with page directive for outputCaching / but prorammatically ! / should i change something in machine.config or root web.config or application web.config for getting affects ?

Comment: see @m.edmondson's answer. You seem to be assuming that the output caching page directive is the same as the code you've written in the `Page_Load` method. This is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Response.Cache
```

All these methods do is modifiy the HTTP headers in the response which ask the browser to do something (in this case modifiy how it cache's).

Have you used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to see these?

I would guess that ASP.net has changed the last-modified date (since it knows the time has changed), however there's a few reasons why the browser would still update:

- The browser could have caching disabled
- The cache could have just been cleared
- It is using some other method to decide the page needed refreshed from the server
- The browser can request whatever it wants

I suggest you research some of these points, however you definitely shouldn't be relying on the browsers cache to ensure the functionality of your app.

Comment: thanks for answer / i test the upper codes in different browsers without any result (mean by clicking refresh button in all of them time is changed , but should n't be) / would u plz let us to know that these codes work for you or not ?

Comment: The thing is, by pressing refresh most browsers functionality is to specifically request the page again (so the time WILL be updated)

Comment: i edit my Q / by pressing refresh most browsers functionality is to specifically request the page again (so the time WILL be updated) -> but should n't!

Comment: by UnComment //Response.Cache.VaryByParams.IgnoreParams = true;
line those codes work perfect / however i marked your answer as my answer because of taking your time on it...thanks a lot for your answer and attention and introducing Fiddler.

Comment: Sorry are you saying you put `Response.Cache.VaryByParams.IgnoreParams = true;` in?

Comment: The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachevarybyparams.ignoreparams.aspx) answers that.  You're telling asp.net to ignore parameters passed to it, so in turn can cache the page